# Webpack email templates

Tags: webpack

I want to use Webpack for bundling my email templates.

I pretty much have a .html file for each of the templates, which references a common .scss file for styles.

I want the styles to be inlined in the HTML

Is this possible?

Comment: This almost seems more like a job for a task runner like Gulp.

Comment: I was under the impression that webpack could also be used as taskrunner

Comment: Good idea, I like Webpack but Grunt examples are everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use webpack, seems to me this is a job for `inline-style-loader`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-style-loader

There's a demo for how to integrate this into your `webpack.config.js` file here: https://github.com/jbsouvestre/inline-style-loader/tree/master/demo

Answer (score -1):

You should use a gulp workflow with Juice ( https://github.com/Automattic/juice ), it should fit your needs !

Cf the doc :

> To inline HTML without getting remote resources, using default
>   options:
>
> `var juice = require('juice');`
>
> `var result = juice("<style>div{color:red;}</style><div/>");`
>
> result will be:
>
> `<div style="color: red;"></div>`